# Set hidden input fields and submit data on same button click

Tags: php, jquery

I have a situation where when a user clicks on the table button then api is called with the details those details then are then set in the hidden input field to be posted or sent or submitted to the next page.

I could add a popup when the button is click and submit the data on the second button click which will be in the popup modal but I dont want that.

My motive is that when the user clicks the button then he should go to the next page and that page should have the details which were fetched by the api on the first page `res.name` and `res.code` in this case. If you have a better way to achieve this then please enlighten.

```
<form action='/veri'>
<table>
<tr><td><button>fetch data</button></td><tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="i1">
<input type="hidden" id="i2">
</form>
```

Jquery

```
 $("button").click(function(){
//there is also a ajax api call here.
$.ajax({
            url: "services.php",
            type: "get",
            beforeSend: function() { 
                 // $("#number").html("Loading Please Wait......");
            },
             success: function(res) {
//set dta
      $("i1").val(res.name);
      $("i2").val(res.code);
    });
              }
```

Comment: you did not show any api call in your example.  Just call submit in the success function of the api call